# Confusion on 1990 B1 Putnam question

Tags: calculus, integration, contest-math

> Find all real-valued continuously differentiable function $f$ on the real line such that for all $x$ 
>   $$(f(x))^2=\int_0^x(f(t))^2+(f’(t))^2\,\mathrm{d}t+1990$$

So the solution makes sense up to a certain point, we take the derivative of this on both sides and obtain 
$$2f(x)f’(x)=(f(x))^2+(f’(x))^2$$ 
Upon rearranging we find 
$$(f(x)-f’(x))^2=0$$
So $f(x)=Ce^x$. Since now we can solve for $c$ by seeing that $f(0)=\pm\sqrt{1990}$. My problem is that if we go back to the original with $f(x)=Ce^x$ then we get 
\begin{align*}
(Ce^x)^2&=\int_0^x2(Ce^t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t+1990\\
&=C^2e^{2x}+1990
\end{align*}
So it seems like $f(x)$ will never satisfy this because $0\neq1990$. Am I missing something here? Any value of $C$ wouldn’t do this as far as I can tell. Every solution says the same thing that $f(x)=\pm\sqrt{1990}e^x$ so what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

\begin{align}
\int_0^x((Ce^t)^2+(Ce^t)^2)dt+1990&=\int_0^x2C^2e^{2t}dt+1990\\
&=C^2e^{2x}-C^2+1990\\
&=C^2e^{2x}
\end{align}
while on the left
$$(Ce^x)^2=C^2e^{2x}.$$

Comment: Ah I made a dumb mistake and assumed when you plug in 0 you get 0. Thank you!

Comment: Easy mistake to make

Answer (score 1):

In evaluating the definite integral, you forgot to subtract the antiderivative evaluated at the lower bound of the integral.